# display &amp; as & using angularjs without using ng-bind-html in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

this example shows my problem (I have copied it from one of the posts in stackoverflow)
http://plnkr.co/edit/yG79IZUI5i97UZj40ddn?p=preview

In the above example, look at this code

```
<li>{{text}}</li>
```

I want to achieve what ng-bind-html does, but cant use it.

I want to use it in jsp i.e

```
<c:out value="{{text}}"/>
```

In my case text= `this &amp; that`. I want to display it on the screen as `this & that`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try using `text.html_safe`.
This way you tell Rails the string is safe to output</strike>

EDIT: Nevermind, I'm dumb!

Anyway though, I believe there is no other way to print HTML through Angular as it take care of the sanization. You can find more info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize).

Comment: I have gone through $sanitize and $sce and even tried but in vain...I have tried : $sce.trustAsHtml and $sanitize(text) but it is not returning the expected results